# How do I use bash to blank only PART of a drive?

Tags: bash, terminal

My company is having to change a lot of hard drives from one type of program to another. We have written a script that blanks an entire drive and then writes the program+OS onto the drive. (Don't ask why this needs to be done this way, just know that it is the way it is.) My problem is that some drives are quite small, only 60-80GB, but some are 150+, which takes a considerable amount of time.

The programs that are on these drives are of varying size, and I'd like to specify only the part of the drive that needs to be blanked inside the terminal. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How would you delineate which part of the drive?  Are you saying a specific folder/path on the filesystem, or some set of blocks on the device?

Comment: The only thing on these drives are these programs, they start at the beginning of the drive and the rest is free space, and I don't want to have to go through and zero out all the blank space, it just takes too long.

Comment: what command are you using to zero out the drive?

Comment: dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=1M conv=notrunc

Comment: Are you sure it's ok to leave existing data on the drive? You said "Don't ask why", but I'm asking: if there's a reason to erase the drive in the first place, there's probably a good reason to erase all of it.

Comment: The program is one that is borrowed from another company, we have no way of editing anything in it except zeroing the drive and rewriting it. They have given us permission to do this, but will not let us access any of their files or anything that could be of use to us.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it sounds like you just want to end up with blank drives but some of the drives are mostly blank to start with so you want to only zero out the parts that are written to.  The problem would be, you have no guarantee which parts are written to unless you check, and if you are checking you may as well overwrite while you are doing so.  Anyway, `dd` is fast if you set a large enough block size:

```
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda bs=100M`
```

You could just try adjusting `bs` until it fits the performance you are looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)#Block_size

**---- EDIT ----**

The same wiki page states:

> The `bs=4k` option makes dd read and write 4 kilobytes at a time. This
>   makes the whole process a lot faster on any relatively modern system.